# How can I anchor a tall cabinet to a pony wall or half wall?

Tags: walls, cabinets, storage

I have a half wall around 40 inches tall. We were thinking of using that wall for storage. The cabinets we are looking at about 60 - 65 inches in height. Any ideas on how to anchor these cabinets to wall? We can secure it at the 38 inch height. But I am not sure if this is enough. Are there any other options?

We don't have the storage cabinets picked out. We are just starting to look at options. These cabinets will be be resting on carpeted floor. We were looking at these [cabinets](https://www.sauder.com/furniture/424001/storage-cabinet).

Comment: The cabinet you linked isn't intended to be mounted to a wall. It's freestanding. The back panel wouldn't offer any real support in that way.

Answer (score 3):

Realistically securing the cabinet anywhere above half way up the cabinet is going to be effective in stopping it from falling.

so securing at 38" will be just fine.

Comment: Many cabinets come with a bracket to attach to the top and wall. That could be attached to the side of the cabinet. I'd suggest putting the bracket near the top of the half-wall so that it goes into the top plate, that way there's no worry about finding a stud to screw it into.

Comment: if it has a cardboard (equivalent) back secure the sides to the top plate of the wall. eg: using a small repair bracket. and screws

Comment: a small bracket installed internally is invisible while the solid doors are closed.